# Populate navigation properties when used in method passed to Where clause

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an endpoint which should list all Candidatures filtered by search term, so what I do is to create a method which accepts candidature entity and searchTerm as params. Then I pass that method to Where clause, but the problem is that I got `NullReferenceException` because navigation properties are nulls. If I put statement inside Where clause instead of the method then it doesn't `throw Exception`. The question is how to fix this, but I want to keep the external method because there will be a lot more logic, but I need to have access to all `navigation properties` i.e. they should be populated.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm))
{
    query = query.Where(c => FilterBySearchTerm(c, searchTerm));
}

var result = await query.Select(c => new CandidaturesResponseModel()
{
    Id = c.Id,
    Name = c.PrimaryMember.FullName, // that's filled
}).ToListAsync();
```

---

```
private bool FilterBySearchTerm(Candidature c, string searchTerm)
{
    return c.PrimaryMember.FirstName.Contains(searchTerm); // here is the exception because PrimaryMember navigation property is null. So I want this to be filled.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're materializing the query by using your `FilterBySearchTerm` method. EF cannot translate random methods to SQL, so it has to go ahead and run the query, get the results back and then apply your `Where`. EF would actually throw an exception in the past, but EF Core handles this silently.

Anyways, once the query is run, you're done. Your filtering is happening in-memory, and at that point, without an `Include`, your related entities are not there to work with. Long and short, you'll need to build your filter in place (rather than using a separate method) in order for EF to be able to translate that to SQL.

An alternative approach which may serve you better is pass a queryable to your `FilterBySearchTerm` method. For example, instead of doing:

```
query = query.Where(c => FilterBySearchTerm(c, searchTerm));
```

Do

```
query = FilterBySearchTerm(query, searchTerm);
```

Then, inside `FilterBySearchTerm`, you can directly apply `Where` clauses to the passed in query. That allows you to build an actual query that EF can understand, while also encapsulating the logic.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking the same but Where returns IQueryable so this should mean it's not yet materialized, also when chaining select linq to the query still have access to navigation properties and materializing happens only after chaining ToList. I Updated code in my first post, so check it again. Also your example would do the work, but I'm curious why this happens.

Comment: "Where returns IQueryable so this should mean it's not yet materialized" - That's not true. `IQueryable` is a LINQ thing. It's a structure that's is *LINQ queryable*. Has nothing to do with whether or not a database query has been made.

Comment: I found a solution also, If those random method returns the expression instead of bool, then it works.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `Include` method to add `PrimaryMember`

```
  query = query.Include(x=> x.PrimaryMember).Where(c => FilterBySearchTerm(c, searchTerm));
```

Comment: Yeah, but if I don't need all of the properties of PrimaryMembers, thats not cool solution. I'm pretty sure there is anything better.